# Why don't we see websites hashing passwords before sending them?

Tags: security

(Note about the question title: by "we" I mean myself)

Everytime I log on to any website, I have this thought that website asking me for my password and sending it back to the server is just basic security engineering. Why do all the websites send my plaintext password (at most over SSL) instead of hashing it with some javascript code first?

Comment: What about the salt? Does the user need to remember that as well?

Comment: The salt could either be constant, stored in the database and passed to the user, or pre-generated for a massive number of tokens.

Comment: In the end, none of those ideas are going to make the transmission of the data more secure.

Comment: Nope, they are not, but they'd lead to transmission of less sensitive data - not a password which might be used by the visitor on more than one website, but a unique hash that is basically harmless if sniffed.

Comment: The problem is the hash, which still allows the password to be found.

Comment: There are already alternatives on the market that are better at this like SecurID, smart cards and others. Don't be too focused on passwords only. SSL already solves this problem and does a lot more.

Comment: Obvious question, what if I don't use JS? Can I use your site? do you have server side code to deal with both options? Wouldn't that give attackers a clear idea of what structure your passwords are on the database? or you would double encode them, once on client and once on the server? ...

Answer (score 6):

JavaScript is client-side code that runs in browsers and hence is very defeatable, so there really is very little point in using it to encrypt passwords.

[SSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) is a cryptographic protocol that encrypts the data between clients and servers, so is considered sufficient without the addition of easily broken, visible client-side code. JavaScript may however be used to verify that a password meets certain standards of strength, such as the number of alphanumeric characters, case, and symbols as required by a server-side application/database.

Comment: About the first paragraph - I didn't mean password encryption, I meant hashing. Calling something, say, salted sha512, on the password on the client side, then sending it to the server to avoid it from ever reaching the server. Doesn't that change things a bit?

Comment: Same thing. Code transmitted from a server to client has to be readable on the client-side. Anything else would require a browser extension specific to the site. [Salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)) is also a one-way function used to protect data on the same computer/server it was run on.

Comment: Yes, the code would have to be readable and it doesn't sound like a problem to me. I don't understand it yet - I believe that you wouldn't send the real password over any media and it's definitely good for security.

Comment: You might ask yourself what the difference is between sending a one-way hash of a password versus the password - a salted password would add randomness that the server would not be able to unsalt, so it would have to store that. Obviously, if there was a better way, sites would already be doing it :-)

Comment: Okay, I got it now. Still, if it was only the salted hash being sent (with the salt being fixed), sniffing/exploiting the server wouldn't mean that if someone uses the same password on multiple sites, he's automatically got a big problem.

Comment: With SSL, the communication between the client and server is encrypted, and passwords on the server should be encrypted as well, so adding JavaScript that can be read and reversed isn't going to effectively improve upon that.

Comment: Yes, the communication between client and server is encrypted, but once the server gets the transmission, it able to decrypt it. Which sounds like a security problem to me.

Comment: Once again, client-side JavaScript isn't going to protect what server admins need to do on the server-side to protect data.

Comment: @d33tah basically poutting it in a nutshell if you use a salt on javascript if people are looking for it you have to declare your salt on the javascript. If you do it client side this goes completely against the general idea of the salt being secret and unique to your website. All they would have to do is run a list of all the words and your salt + the hashing function you used and there you have it! 90% of your passwords will have been cracked. Client side is a big no no

Answer (score 0):

I'll chime in here with an attempt at an answer: We don't see it b/c it hasn't become a big deal to those commissioning the websites and knowledge of alternatives isn't very public.

I've started using [SRP (Secure Remote Password) protocol](http://srp.stanford.edu/) and as you can see from https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=srp , there's a good amount of interest in the security realm of things, but nada on https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/search?q=srp .

Now, I'm **not** saying SRP is the end-all, be-all of security, but it addresses your concern and the concern of storing the password anywhere after being entered into the login form.

There's no perfect solution until Heisenberg's Uncertainty Principle is mastered from the point of entry to the point of reception, but better and better methods arise and take their time to become "standards".

Answer (score 0):

Password over SSL is secure to atleast some point. And hashing the password with client side Javascript is good but doesn't enhance your security much. It's easily beatable.

The primary hashing algorithm must be hidden from eavesdrop for higher security. Because for better & higher security, passwords must be salted & these salt phrase must be hidden invisible to anyone.

Hope it answers your doubt.